# `dired-do-search` not resuming search

Tags: dired, search

I've been using the `dired-do-search` for a long time to find regexp
matches in marked files in a directory.  If there were more matches, you
could resume the search and find the next match with `M-,` but it
stopped working for me somewhere around the 24.4 or 24.5 release.
Currently I'm on 25.0.50.2 and when I do `M-,` after the first match is
found, I'm getting `xref-pop-marker-stack: Marker stack is empty`.

Can somebody help me fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: See my comment on Drew's answer: if you call `M-x tags-loop-continue` does it do what you expect?

Comment: @glucas Yes, the `tags-loop-continue` does what I expected. I imagine it should be bound to `M-,` by default as @Drew suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug.  If you see this behavior when you start Emacs without an init file (emacs -Q), then consider reporting the problem: M-x report-emacs-bug. If you do not see it from emacs -Q, then recursively bisect your init file to locate the problem it introduces.

Comment: I've noticed this as well in Emacs 25. I have worked around it for now by adding my own binding for `tags-loop-continue`, which is the command that continues the dired search. I believe `M-,`  used to be bound to `tags-loop-continue` but is now bound to `xref-pop-marker-stack` -- which does nothing in this context.

Comment: @glucas: Good info to add to a bug report. ;-) Perhaps someone didn't `grep` for occurrences of `tags-loop-continue` when changing the command bound to `M-,`. ;-)